# variable set but not used Warning but also error undeclared identifier

Tags: c, scoping, undeclared-identifier

The debugger tells me I don't use my variable but also that it is not declared. What is going on here? is an if statement it's own scope? Somehow it seems to be the case that an array of fixed length is not in the same scope inside of an if block.

**My Minimal example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void nullarray(int start,int end,  char array[]){
if(start<end) // TODO used to be <=
    {
    array[start]='0';
    nullarray(++start,end,array);
    }else{array[start]='\0';}

}


int main()
{
    int commaindex2=-1;
    int mostdecimaldigits=6;

      if(commaindex2==-1){
            char decimalnum2[1];decimalnum2[0]='0';
            }
    else{
    char decimalnum2[mostdecimaldigits]; // get enought store incl filling up zeros
    nullarray(0,mostdecimaldigits,decimalnum2); // write zeros to array

    }
     printf("%s", decimalnum2);
}
```

**Debugger Output**

```
||=== Build: Debug in test4 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\main.c||In function 'main':|
D:\main.c|20|warning: variable 'decimalnum2' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|
D:\main.c|27|error: 'decimalnum2' undeclared (first use in this function)|
D:\main.c|27|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

**however this works fine**

```
int main()
{
    int commaindex2=55;
    int mostdecimaldigits=6;
    int num;
      if(commaindex2==-1){
           num=1 ;
            }
    else{
   num=mostdecimaldigits;

    }
     char decimalnum2[num];
     nullarray(0,num,decimalnum2);
     printf("%s", decimalnum2);
}
```

Comment: *"is an if statement its own scope"* - Yes, since C99

Comment: At least since C89, in fact, @UnholySheep.  Block scope is described very much the same way in C89 as it is in C99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here? Is an if statement it's own scope?

Yes - the `if` statement (or, to be precise, the curly braces following it) defines its own scope, as do the braces after the `else` statement (but that's a *different* scope).

Thus, your declarations `char decimalnum2[1];` and `char decimalnum2[mostdecimaldigits];` (in the `if` and `else` blocks, respectively) define variables (separate, unrelated ones) that are valid **only within the braces in which they occur**.

So, the statement: `printf("%s", decimalnum2);`, which is outside both blocks, is attempting to use an undeclared variable - hence the error.

Further, the statement `decimalnum2[0]='0';` (in the `if` block) assigns a value to the (block-local) variable that is then never used - hence the warning.

Quick Solution: You need to put the `char decimalnum2[mostdecimaldigits];` declaration both **before** and **outside** the `if … else` blocks, and remove the two declarations *inside* those blocks.

Answer (score 2):

A set of curly braces starts a new scope, so in your first piece of code `decimalnum2` is declared in two distinct scopes, one inside of an `if` block and one inside of an `else` block.  Both of these are distinct variables and no longer exist once that scope is left.

This is why you get the warning and error you do.  You set the variable but don't use it within the scope it is declared in, and you attempt to use it outside of its scope.

Answer (score 0):

As UnholySheep Pointed out there is block scope in C . This means the variable stops existing after } of the if block. Thus the values can't be printed.

[Details on this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/)